# How can I increase the size of a memory block in MPLAB?

Tags: memory, embedded, pic, microchip

The Microchip PIC MPLAB (MCC18) compiler segments its memory into 256 chunks ( 0x100 ).

How can I create an array larger than 256 bytes?

```
char buffer[256];
```

Just to get to 256 I needed to make a seperate segment with a `#pragma`

```
#pragma udata segment_name
char buffer[256];
#pragma udata
```

So I can either force MCC18 to let allocate a larger buffer? or combine two memory segments?

Answer (score 6):

Pasting answer from:

http://forum.microchip.com/printable.aspx?m=39357

Just in case it goes away.

> In Three Easy Steps Step 1: Assign the
>   variable into a named section in
>   source code:
>
> ```
> #pragma udata big_scn
> char big_array[0x180];
> #pragma udata
> ```
>
> Step 2: Create the larger region in
>   the linker script:  Before:
>
> ```
> DATABANK NAME=gpr3 START=0x300 END=0x3FF
> DATABANK NAME=gpr4 START=0x400 END=0x4FF
> ```
>
> After:
>
> ```
> DATABANK NAME=big_scn START=0x300 END=0x47F PROTECTED
> DATABANK NAME=gpr4    START=0x480 END=0x4FF
> SECTION  NAME=big_scn RAM=big_scn
> ```
>
> Step 3: Reference only through a
>   pointer:
>
> ```
> char *big_array_ptr = &big_array[0];
> big_array_ptr[0x100] = 5;
> while( big_array_ptr[x] != 20 )
> ```

NOTE: I believe you can still reference the array directly instead of using a pointer.  Seems to work for me.

The same information can be found in the following document:

[MPLAB C18 C Compiler Getting Started Guide](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/MPLAB_C18_Getting_Started_51295f.pdf)

Page 104.

Comment: Thank you for putting the solution instead of just a link that can die.

Comment: Note that if you do stuff like this, using the paid C18 compiler instead of the student one becomes more important. It can under circumstances optimize away bankloading

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps someone with more knowledge will prove me wrong, but I don't think it's possible to do what you want.  If the memory in your device is divided into segments of 256 bytes, then you can't have an array spanning them, AFAIK.  If you did, it would have to jump through all sorts of hoops to let you treat the array as contiguous memory -- it would have to check each index you use to figure out which segment it should be in, then compute the offset and access it, or if you're accessing the array using pointer arithmetic, it must figure out what you're trying to access, which may be non-obvious or even unknown at compile time.  I don't think it has a single memory model that it can use for all circumstances because of the way some memory locations are common across banks (I think the program counter is one such location), etc.  I'm speaking largely from a knowledge of the typical PIC architecture and some experience with third-party C compilers.  I don't have much experience with MPLAB itself, so take my answer with a grain of salt.

It may be possible for you to get around the restriction by allocating an array of pointers and then initializing each pointer to a new instance of whatever data type you want to store in it (I'm assuming a struct or something larger than a pointer), as this will not require the memory to be contiguous.  Dynamic memory allocation on PICs is expensive, however, so this may not be a good option for you.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem!I was going to use this method: http://www.hobbytronics.co.uk/c18-large-data-arrays 
But when I added linker without any change to the project and compile the project I got this error 
         // $Id: 18f2550.lkr,v 1.3 2005/03/24 04:17:19 craigfranklin Exp $
         // File: 18f2550.lkr
         // Sample linker script for the PIC18F2550 processor

```
    LIBPATH .

    //CODEPAGE   NAME=vectors    START=0x0            END=0x29           PROTECTED
    CODEPAGE   NAME=page       START=0x0            END=0x6FFB
    CODEPAGE   NAME=boot       START=0x6FFC         END=0x7FFF         PROTECTED
    CODEPAGE   NAME=idlocs     START=0x200000       END=0x200007       PROTECTED
    CODEPAGE   NAME=config     START=0x300000       END=0x30000D       PROTECTED
    CODEPAGE   NAME=devid      START=0x3FFFFE       END=0x3FFFFF       PROTECTED
    CODEPAGE   NAME=eedata     START=0xF00000       END=0xF000FF       PROTECTED

    ACCESSBANK NAME=accessram  START=0x0            END=0x5F
    DATABANK   NAME=gpr0       START=0x60           END=0xFF
    DATABANK   NAME=gpr1       START=0x100          END=0x1FF
    DATABANK   NAME=gpr2       START=0x200          END=0x2FF
    DATABANK   NAME=gpr3       START=0x300          END=0x3FF
    DATABANK   NAME=usb4       START=0x400          END=0x4FF          PROTECTED
    DATABANK   NAME=usb5       START=0x500          END=0x5FF          PROTECTED
    DATABANK   NAME=usb6       START=0x600          END=0x6FF          PROTECTED
    DATABANK   NAME=usb7       START=0x700          END=0x7FF          PROTECTED
    ACCESSBANK NAME=accesssfr  START=0xF60          END=0xFFF          PROTECTED

    SECTION    NAME=CONFIG     ROM=config
    SECTION    NAME=bank1      RAM=gpr1
    SECTION    NAME=usbram4    RAM=usb4
    SECTION    NAME=usbram5    RAM=usb5
    SECTION    NAME=eeprom     ROM=eedata
```

error:
18f2550.lkr:5: warning: (374) missing basic type; int assumed
18f2550.lkr:5: error: (314) ";" expected

whay?Everything is true!
 I am using mplabx  v 2.0 and Mplab xc8 v 1.31